# How can i get error report in detailed manner in Locust Load testing tool?

Tags: locust

If I am hitting any web page in Locust Load testing tool means ,it throws some error.I want to get the error in detailed summary.

How can I get error report in detailed manner.Is there any function like trace-back in locust it will be used to print the error list in detail.

My coding is like this:

class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):

```
try:
  @task(1)
  def index(self):
      self.client.get("/")
except Exception as e:
     print e.msg
```

If I test any url like this https://www.python.org/ it will throw error like in below screen shot
[image]

Error :ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('''',)),)

I want to get this error in detail.

Answer (score 2):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to see the traceback for the error that happened in the web app that you are doing HTTP requests against. In that case it's not something you can do in Locust. You need to set up that kind of error reporting / logging within the app that you are load testing.

(please comment and clarify if I've misinterpreted your question, and I'll update the answer).